# Missing text on suggested edit list in profile

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, profile-page, activity-summary

See below, taken from the suggestions part of the activity tab of my profile:

[image]

I'm not too sure why there isn't a title/link after the "on", but I guess something should be there, or the display/wording should be changed.

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior on my profile.

Comment: @bluefeet - You are correct the tag is no longer exists. So it is not showing anything. Looking at [my suggested edits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187824/hims056?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) on Meta, it is showing on which tag [I have suggested edits](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq2EL.png) because those tags are exists.

Comment: @hims056 That exactly what I see, my [suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) show the links with current tags but missing tags have just the on.